# Will this work? AC transformer, 15V 1ampere, center tap, voltage drop

Tags: resistors, transformer, ac

[image: Will this work?]

I am trying to drop the voltage of a torodial transormer to 12VAC while the configuration the same. 15-0-15 to 12-0-12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your chosen resistors you have a 15 Ω load on each 15 V supply. From Ohm's Law you can show that this will cause 1 A to flow through your resitive divider. Now you have 100% load on the transformer and nothing left to power anything else.

You could double the resistor values to reduce the current but when you connect a load in parallel with the 12 Ω resistors the voltage will fall due to the increased current in the parallel loads.

Your options are:

1. Buy the right transformer.
2. Remove 20% of the secondary windings.
3. Tell us what your load is and why you want 12 - 0 - 12 and we may be able to suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> *Will this work? Ac transformer, 15v 1amp, center tap, voltage drop*

It will produce the voltages but may not be that great at sustaining those voltages when loads are connected to +12 volt AC or -12 volts AC. If you are looking for a regulated AC voltage you should go down a different path.

Plus, you are dissipating quite a bit of power in those resistors. Is this what you really want I wonder.

Comment: This is to power a small 25w amp which requires 0.83 amps. I calculated that I will keep the 1 amp from the transformer. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, it won't work at all. You are using up the available power from the transformer in the resistors. If you try to make those resistors higher value you just won't get the power into your amplifier so, no, it won't work. Get a transformer that is more suitable.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarity. I realise my mistake.

Comment: Does the amplifier have a data sheet or manual - maybe it can take 30 volts AC? Maybe you can use dropper diodes. Maybe you have handy another transformer with a dual 3 volt secondary that can be bodged in @inso ?

Comment: I did think of another winding on the transformer to produce 12v. Or dropping the resistors to 0.75 and 3 ohm

Comment: Dropping the resistors as you mention causes a current of 4 amps to flow and pop goes the transformer.

Comment: The penny has dropped. I will get the right ohms for the amps.

Comment: @inso no, there is not "the right ohms for the amps" at all. You can't use dropper resistors without compromising things too much. Too small and the transformer burns, too big and you get very little power to your amplifier. There is no single goldilocks value either because the current into the amplifier will change depending on what signal is going to the speaker and that = no goldilocks resistor values.

Comment: oh... I'll buy a 12v transformer. Thank you. I do feel stupid. Was wondering why I was going in circles!

Comment: @inso yes, I agree (or strip the 15 volt one down if you can and count the secondary turns and remove 20% of them).

Comment: I'll keep the 15v as is for later down the line for a different amp. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @inso in case your are interested in understanding the motivation for folk giving free help [read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what might be expected from you to guarantee sustained and decent future help.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways which are much better.

It's common in the guitar amp world to reduce input AC (for vintage amps that were designed when US standard was 110V) because there is no voltage regulator in a vintage tube amp. They are dependent on the wall voltage.

Try this clever trick [geofex.com/Article_Folders/mosfet_folly/mosfetfolly.htm](http://geofex.com/Article_Folders/mosfet_folly/mosfetfolly.htm) About 1/2 way down the page, look for "A MOSFET B+ Reducer".

It can also be done with a simply wired 2nd "Bucking transformer".  Super easy to wire up, but more expensive and takes up more space. [antiqueradios.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=131048](http://antiqueradios.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=131048)

Comment: I did look at this and was looking at the buck idea and looked into something like mosfets but I am a complete virgin and would have do do a lot of learning. It's just easier to buy the right transformer. But thank you.

Comment: @inso    Yes -   1000% easier to 'just buy the right transformer"   ;)